# React on drag-down gesture and prevent reload

Tags: javascript, web-applications, event-handling, gesture

**Intro:** When visiting a website on a mobile device and the website is already scrolled to top, then you can drag the page further down (as with many apps) into "negative" space to reload the page.

Now in my case, I have a web app that looks and behaves like an app. So I see that sometimes people use this drag gesture in order to close an overlay. However, the website gets reloaded instead - since this is the browser default behaviour.

Can I somehow prevent the page reload and/or react on that specific gesture?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - but I was thinking, the overlay could use a `martin-top` and be scrollable, then react on `scroll` could work...

Comment: What's martin-top?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `margin-top` 

Comment: If by overlay you mean some kind of modal, then even if you add margin-top to it, it would reach the top of the scroll inside the modal and then would cause reload just as well. That what happens in my case at least. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I have an overlay that covers the whole screen, but it could still have a margin-top. When showing it, it would be scrolled automatically such that the margin is no more visible, and when the user scrolls up again, it could disappear

Comment: Got it, I ended up doing something similar. It's not the perfect solution, but it works.

Comment: I can imagine, my solution would also not be ideal. Maybe html will support this natively in the future...